# Searching an element in a list

Tags: java, list, collections

How can I search in a List? Is there any in build function?

```
public void searchEmployee(int empId) {
    Iterator<Employee> iterator = list1.iterator();
    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        if (iterator.next().getEmpid() == empId) {
            System.out.println("the searched employee is ::");
            iterator.remove();
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not yet.  There will be better support in Java 8, but for now you can make the code simpler

```
for(Employee e: list1)
    if(e.getEmptId() == empId)
        System.out.println("The searched item is " + e);
```

Comment: Oh,My twin brother :(

Answer (score 1):

`List#contains()` method can be used. But in your case, since you need to search it based on `empId`, you need to override the `equals()` in your `Employee` class like this.

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (obj != null) {
        Test other = (Test) obj;
        return i == other.i;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

And then you can do something like this:

```
list1.remove(yourEmp);
```

Comment: what if `empObject.equals(null)` :/ ?

Comment: @SubhrajyotiMajumder - The `null` check should do?!

Comment: No need if the object is null equals will always return false. So this is OK.

Answer (score 1):

In your case, As simple as you get is

```
for (Employee e : list) { 
    if (e.getEmpid() == empId) {
       //found here .break
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

List has `.contains(Object o)` and `.remove(Object o)` 
So the better way would be

```
public void removeEmployee(Employee e) {
   if (listEmplyees.contains(e)) {
       listEmplyees.remove(e);
   }
}
```

for Emplyee object or for Id:

```
public void removeEmployee(int i) {
   for(Employee e: listEmplyees) {
       if(e.getId == i) {
           listEmplyees.remove(e);
       }
   }
}
```

Or you could store Employees in Map by their id and there would be easier to delete by id. And if you want to ensure, that employees would never be repeated - use Set and override hashCode and equals in your Employee class, so you could place break in your search loop, when you find the same object.

Comment: What about a comparator on Employee.empId?

Comment: Yeap, that seems nice to me too. Make class Emplyee implements Comparable<Employee> and override compareTo method comparing ids of employyes and than use SortedSet<Emplyee> employees = new TreeSet<Emplyee>(); Seems nice realization too :)

Answer (score 0):

List has `.contains()` method through which you can check whether list contains that object or not. For ex : I have a list `products` which stores the object of product in list.

```
List<Product> products;
if(products.contains(tempProduct)){
     //    do some operations
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try use built in function binarySearch:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#binarySearch(java.util.List, T, java.util.Comparator)